# Writing the recurrence $O_t=-\frac1{T_w}\sum_{i=t-T_p}^{t-1}O_i-\frac1{T_i}\sum_{i=1}^{t-T_p-1}O_i+B_t$ in terms of its initial value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, pattern-recognition

I want to write the following solely in terms of its initial value $O_1$
$$ 
 O_t = -  \frac{1}{T_w}  \sum_{i=t-T_p}^{t-1} O_{i} 
 - \frac{1}{T_i}     \sum_{i=1}^{t-T_p-1} O_i
 + B_t  
 $$
where

- $T_w , T_i$ are non zero constants
- $T_p$ is positive integer
- $B_t$ is some function of t
- Define $O_i = 0  ,  \; B_i = 0\quad \forall \; i < 1$

I'd expanded the first 3 terms in order to find pattern , we may compare the blue terms .
I found a pattern , like the coefficients have the form $a_{n+1} = a_n + a_n^2 $ but I don't have a close form for it . Furthermore , there seems to be other patterns as well .
[image: expaninsion]

Context : above is actually a model for supply chain , with $\frac{1}{T_w} ,\frac{1}{T_i}  $ as proportional gain (they are 2 indepedent feedback controllers) , you don't see the error because I've already simplified the expression . I want to do this because I do have the  analytic expressions for $O_1$ , so this is the first step to prepare for optimization .

Comment: I suppose $T_p$ is a positive integer not just constant

Comment: I made an error in my previous comment (now deleted): the order here is not constant, as there is a direct contribution from all preceding values of $O_i$ (not just propagation). This usually prevents analytical solution just by itself.

Comment: @lan could you explain a bit more behind this intuition ? I think an analytical solution in this case means some explicit mathematical function such that its input parameters are independent so that we could analyze the effect of individual parameters on function value .

Comment: @lan here I want to make $O_1$ as the only input parameter , and it seems like I could do it  by continuing my above expansion  : see that $O_t$ originally depends on $O_i , i = 1,...,t-1$ (1st blue term) , then on $O_i , i = 1,...,t-2$ (2nd blue term)

Comment: In principle you can do that, but you don't get any nice expression. What you get is basically equivalent to doing numerics unless you are interested in one specific time (and even then the expression you get will be nightmarish).

Comment: @lan so you don't see any pattern (in the expansion above) that could possibly make it a nice expression ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Considering first $T_p = 3$ from

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 \frac{o_0+o_1+o_2}{T_w}+o_3 &=& b_3 \\
 \frac{o_1+o_2+o_3}{T_w}+o_4&=&b_4 \\
 \frac{o_1}{T_i}+\frac{o_2+o_3+o_4}{T_w}+o_5 &=& b_5\\
 \frac{o_1+o_2}{T_i}+\frac{o_3+o_4+o_5}{T_w}+o_6 &=& b_6\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

we can represent a matrix formula as

$$
M_1 O_{t+T_p} + M_2O_t=B_{t+T_p} 
$$

with

$$
\cases{
O_t = (o_{-1},o_0,o_1,o_2)^T\\
M_1 = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{T_w} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{T_w} & \frac{1}{T_w} & 1 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{T_w} & \frac{1}{T_w} & \frac{1}{T_w} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\\
M_2 = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{T_w} & \frac{1}{T_w} & \frac{1}{T_w} \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{T_w} & \frac{1}{T_w} \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{T_i} & \frac{1}{T_w} \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{T_i} & \frac{1}{T_i} \\
\end{array}
\right)
}
$$

and as $M_1$ is invertible we have

$$
O_{t+T_p} + M_1^{-1}M_2O_t=M_1^{-1}B_{t+T_p} 
$$

NOTE

$$
M_1^{-1} = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{1}{T_w} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1-T_w}{T_w^2} & -\frac{1}{T_w} & 1 & 0 \\
 -\frac{(T_w-1)^2}{T_w^3} & \frac{1-T_w}{T_w^2} & -\frac{1}{T_w} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

now assuming $O_t = 0$ we have

$$
O_{t+T_p} = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 b_3 \\
 b_4-\frac{b_3}{T_w} \\
 b_5+\frac{b_3 (1-T_w)}{T_w^2}-\frac{b_4}{T_w} \\
 b_6-\frac{b_3 (T_w-1)^2}{T_w^3}+\frac{b_4 (1-T_w)}{T_w^2}-\frac{b_5}{T_w} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: I'm not very familiar with matrix recurrence , could you give more explicit definition ? like what does your "$O_t$" refer to , does it refer to (in my notation) $(O_t,O_{t-1},O_{t-2},O_{t-3})^T$ ? what's the "propagation matrix" M that relates "$(O_t,O_{t-1},O_{t-2},O_{t-3},...)^T$" and "$(O_{t+1},O_{t},O_{t-1},O_{t-2},...)^T$" ?

Comment: I think $(O_{t+1},O_{t},O_{t-1},O_{t-2},...)^T$  could be modified to $V \cdot (O_{t},O_{t-1},O_{t-2},...)^T$  ?  for some transformation V to make vector lengths equal (it seems possible based on the expansion in my post) . So we may find some matrix M such that $(O_{t+1},O_{t},O_{t-1},O_{t-2},...)^T = V \cdot (O_{t},O_{t-1},O_{t-2},...)^T = M \cdot (O_{t},O_{t-1},O_{t-2},O_{t-3}...)^T$

Comment: I'm actually not sure about whether we could find a (or 2 in your example) constant matrix M to do this , because the length of vectors keeps changing , the dimension of M will need to change . Maybe it illustrates @lan 's idea (in comment above) that the order is not constant and so we cannot find an  analytical solution ?

Comment: Really the developed formula is not a recurrence. An additional unknown was introduced to "square" the formulas: $o_{-1}$